# Get size in bytes of webpage in Android

Tags: android

How can I calculate the file size of an html (just the html) web page with Android?

I tried this:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(fullUrl);

HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

InputStream input = entity.getContent();
int size = input.available();
```

But available() is always returning zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
String content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
byte[] bytes = content.getBytes("UTF8");
```

**UPDATE**

```
URL url = new URL("http://server.com/file.mp3");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
int file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
```

Comment: Is there any way to find out the size *without* first downloading it?

Comment: This is not downloading the whole page is it?

Comment: nope it is not..  check this : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html