# android - Add Horizontal Progress Bar to AysncTask

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an application that will download the source code of a web page from an url and show it in a **TextView**.I also want it show a **Horizontal Progress bar** while the page is being downloaded in the background. I've succeeded in downloading the web page in the background using **Asynctask** but I don't know how to find out the size of the web page and update the progress bar according to the download status in the background.

This is what I'm doing to download the web page source code -

```
package com.example.gc;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView tv;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cd);
    grabURL("http://google.com");
}

public void grabURL(String url) {
    new GrabURL().execute(url);
}

private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;

    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        if (Error != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
          //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Source: " + Content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            tv.setText(Content);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Please help me to show and update the **Horizontal Progress Bar** in my app. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to create Progress Dialog into AsyncTask onPreExecute(). like below:

```
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading ...");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

    try {

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
             //Downloading progress update
             //your downloding logic over here

              /* int lenghtOfFile= urlConnection.getContentLength();
              InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = newFileOutputStream(outputFile);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));*/

                    }

    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
                      //Update Progress
         mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

Here, i show you how to implement Horizontal Progress Dialog into AsyncTask.Now, customized by your own way.

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20323914/1572718) should answer your question. Just make a HTTP request to get the size of the webpage.

As for displaying the progress on your progressBar have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119595/1572718)

Answer (score -1):

```
private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // download page
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```