# Get webpage filesize in Android

Tags: android

i am trying to get in Android the filesize of a webpage when loaded in a webview.
I haven't find any method to get the filesize in Android docs...

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html

Also, the solution to parse the html to string, download after the images,css etc.  with HttpUrlConnection and get their size doesn't sound good to me.
Any ideas guys?

Comment: I went through WebView docs , there is no menthod to find the file size ? Why do you want this ? Is there any special requirement  ? If you explain we can find the good approach to achieve the requirements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u have a file,then you can use the file.length() property to get file size.

Also u can check this link..
[Get size in bytes of webpage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323885/get-size-in-bytes-of-webpage-in-android)

Comment: Saving the file and get the file.length() property is a good solution!          "getContentLength();" solution from link requires page headers contain "content-legth" property